# How to pre-select checkbox in angularJs with ng-checked

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, angularjs, haml

I seem to cannot get this to work. So I have a bunch of genres of movies which I want them to be checked if those are the genres in user database. This is my code

```
%section(ng-controller="UserCtrl" ng-init="user_genres=#{preferred_genres}")
    %ul
         %li(ng:repeat="genre in preferred_genres")
            %input(type = "checkbox" ng:model="preferred_genres[genre]" id="genre-{{$index + 1}}" ng-checked="user_genres['{{genre}}']")
            %label{:for => "genre-{{$index + 1}}"} {{genre}}
```

And this is `#{preferred_genres}` from haml

```
{"Action & Adventure":true,"Animation":true,"Art House & International":true,"Classics":true,"Comedy":true,"Documentary":true,"Drama":true,"Horror":true,"Kids & Family":true,"Musical & Performing Arts":true,"Mystery & Suspense":true,"Romance":true,"Science Fiction & Fantasy":true,"Special Interest":true,"Sports & Fitness":true,"Television":true,"Western":true}
```

So that means every checkbox should be checked. But no checkbox is checked when I load the page. However if I hardcode `ng-checked` to be something like this it works.

```
ng-checked="user_genres['Western']"
```

This is really strange. Please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The value of `ng-checked` needs to be an expression. Get rid of the {{}}. So, something like this:

```
 %input(type = "checkbox" ng-model="preferred_genres[genre]" id="genre-{{$index + 1}}" ng-checked="user_genres[genre]")
```

Also, you don't need to necessarily even have the `ng-checked` directive. If the value of your model is true, then it will be checked for you.