# AngularJs doesn't bind ng-checked with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have googled this and found out that people had this issue, but I haven't found any solution.

So this is my code

```
%section(ng-controller="UserCtrl" ng-init="user_genres=#{preferred_genres}")
    %ul
         %li(ng:repeat="genre in preferred_genres")
            %input(type = "checkbox" ng:model="preferred_genres[genre]" id="genre-{{$index + 1}}" ng-checked="user_genres['{{genre}}']")
            %label{:for => "genre-{{$index + 1}}"} {{genre}}
```

For example if some of the checkboxes are checked due to ng-checked expression is true and on page render. And I didn't actually click the checkbox it again. When it comes to the controller, the scope seems to ignore the one that has been checked because of ng-checked. How do I make them sync nicely?

Comment: Weird I asked this question before the duplicated one. hmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand what the real problem is, but see if this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/bQ5du/) is what you want.  (I obtained a list of preferred_genres from your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225855/how-to-pre-select-checkbox-in-angularjs-with-ng-checked).)

The controller scope property `preferred_genres` is being updated based on the checkbox state:

```
<li ng-repeat="(genre, checked) in preferred_genres">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="preferred_genres[genre]"
   id="genre-{{$index + 1}}">
```

As @dnc253 mentioned in your other post, you probably don't need ng-checked since each item has its own ng-model.

Comment: Also if @toy whants to save original list of 'user_genres' got from server (e.g. reset to original checked), he can add to controller:
$scope.preferred_genres = `angular.copy($scope.user_genres);`