# AngularJS: ng-model not binding to ng-checked for checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-checked

I referred to this before asking this question: [AngularJs doesn't bind ng-checked with ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226439/angularjs-doesnt-bind-ng-checked-with-ng-model)

If `ng-checked` is evaluated to `true` on the `html` side, the `ng-model` is not updated. I can't `ng-repeat` as suggested in the above question because I have to use some styling for each checkbox.

Here is the plunker that I have created to illustrate my problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YsOsPh3vjkPMUUDa6r2t

To see what I want, please open the console, and just click on `Submit` button. Please don't check any checkboxes.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`ngModel` and `ngChecked` are not meant to be used together.

`ngChecked` is expecting an expression, so by saying `ng-checked="true"`, you're basically saying that the checkbox will always be checked by default.

You should be able to just use `ngModel`, tied to a boolean property on your model.  If you want something else, then you either need to use `ngTrueValue` and `ngFalseValue` (which only support strings right now), or write your own directive.

What is it exactly that you're trying to do?  If you just want the first checkbox to be checked by default, you should change your model -- `item1: true,`.

Edit: You don't have to submit your form to debug the current state of the model, btw, you can just dump `{{testModel}}` into your HTML (or `<pre>{{testModel|json}}</pre>`).  Also your `ngModel` attributes can be simplified to `ng-model="testModel.item1"`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/HtdOok8aieBjT5GFZOb3?p=preview

Comment: `ng-checked` is computed to true by a expression. To indicate `ng-model` is not linked, I used true there. While initiating the controller, I want all the checkboxes to be unchecked. After some ajax request, I compute the `ng-checked` to check the checkbox. This is when my `ng-model` is not update.

Comment: @Abilash You should not be using `ngChecked`.  Your model is fine, you just need to set `testModel.item1 = true` in your ajax callback and then call `$scope.$apply()` to update your view.

Comment: We just made the mistake of using `ng-checked` in stead of `ng-model`... never again!

Comment: As per the note on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked
"Note that this(ngChecked) directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior."

Comment: @Langdon i was stucked on this issue for about hours.. your hint *$scope.$apply()* resolved my issue. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Chiming in as well to say that $scope.$apply() solved my issue as well. This makes the checkbox get checked when the value is set after the ajax call fills in the scope data.

Answer (score 14):

You can use ng-value-true to tell angular that your ng-model is a string.

I could only get ng-true-value working if I added the extra quotes like so (as shown in the official Angular docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

```
ng-true-value="'1'"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use `ng-repeat` passing in the value of whatever you're iterating on to the `ng-checked` and from there utilising `ng-class` to apply your styles depending on the result.

I did something similar recently and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can Declare As the in ng-init also getting true

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="testModel['item1']= true">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" ng-model="testModel['item1']"  /> Testing</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" ng-model="testModel['item2']" /> Testing 2</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" ng-model="testModel['item3']" /> Testing 3</label><br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="submit()" value="Submit" />
  </body>
</html>
```

And You Can Select the First One and Object Also Shown here true,false,flase

Comment: There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. See [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Answer (score 1):

### The `ng-model` and `ng-checked` directives should not be used together

From the Docs:

> ## ngChecked
>
> Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside `ngChecked` is truthy.
>
> **Note that this directive should not be used together with `ngModel`**, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.
>
> — [AngularJS ng-checked Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

---

Instead set the desired initial value from the controller:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" ng-model="testModel['item1']" ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶e̶d̶=̶"̶t̶r̶u̶e̶"̶ />
    Testing<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="test" ng-model="testModel['item2']" /> Testing 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="test" ng-model="testModel['item3']" /> Testing 3<br />
<input type="button" ng-click="submit()" value="Submit" />
```

```
$scope.testModel = { item1: true };
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ng-checked` when you use `ng-model`. If you're performing **CRUD** on your HTML Form, just create a model for `CREATE` mode that is consistent with your `EDIT` mode during the data-binding:

#### CREATE Mode: Model with default values only

```
$scope.dataModel = {
   isItemSelected: true,
   isApproved: true,
   somethingElse: "Your default value"
}
```

#### EDIT Mode: Model from database

```
$scope.dataModel = getFromDatabaseWithSameStructure()
```

Then whether `EDIT` or `CREATE` mode, you can consistently make use of your `ng-model` to sync with your database.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while i am working with the angular js migration from 1.2 to 1.3.
The input type checkbox was not triggered if it was initiated from controller as well as the ng change event also not triggered. I tried with all types since ng model along with ng checked wont work.
Then ended with simple thing it worked for me like removing the ng change event by replacing with ng click.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).