# How to bind ng-model to ng-checked boxes

Tags: angularjs

I am having a problem binding Angular ng-check to ng-model, that is ng-model does do not recognize the selected state of my check boxes.

Here is a description(Its a much larger code base but I have tailored to minimize code).

On page load in JavaScript I initialize my products and set the default values:

```
$scope.products = {}
$scope.SetProductsData = function() {
    var allProducts;
    allProducts = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Book",
        selected: true
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Toy",
        selected: true
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "Phone",
        selected: true
      }]
```

I have a master control in my view that list a check box  for each 3 products(Book,Toy and phone):These are checked by default

```
<div style="float:left" ng-init="allProducts.products = {}" >
    <div ng-repeat="p in Data.products">
        <div style="font-size: smaller">
            <label><input id="divPlatorm"  ng-model="products[p.name]" ng-init="products[p.name] = true" type="checkbox"/>
                {{p.name}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then a table that have the same products repeated in rows:

```
<div ng-repeat="line in lineProducts" ng-init="line.products = {}">
    <div id="sc-p-enc" ng-repeat="p in Data.products">
        <div id="sc-p-plat" style="font-size: smaller">
            <label id="pl-label"><input ng-checked="products[p.name]"  ng-model="line.products[p.name]"  ng-init="line.products[p.name] = true" type="checkbox"/>                                    
                {{p.name}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I check/unchecked the master products the corresponding check boxes changes in the rows. So if I have 100 rows with   (Book,Toy and phone) the unchecked Toy I can see where all toys are unchecked in the rows.

When I send the data to my controller I can still see all Toys = true even though they were unchecked.

If I physically go to the row then unchecked each toy and send the data to my controller Toys = False.

How can I get the check boxes selected state to change when controlled from the master check-boxes?

I have followed the post found here but I dont think this applies to my scenario:
[AngularJS: ng-model not binding to ng-checked for checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601018/angularjs-ng-model-not-binding-to-ng-checked-for-checkboxes)

Comment: There are parts of the code missing. A fiddle/plunk would help. Other than that: you are reusing ids inside `ng-repeat`; it will result in many elements with the same id in the document. And you are using `ng-init` extensively. I believe `ng-init` inserts procedural logic in the view which is generally not a best practice.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the `ng-checked` in the table is binding to `products[p.name]`, which the `ng-model` in your master control in the view also binding to. But the `ng-model` in your table is binding to another property, `line.products[p.name]`.

I think you probably don't need `ng-checked` in the table since each item has its own `ng-model`. So you might change your table view to

```
<label id="pl-label"><input ng-model="line.products[p.name]" type="checkbox"/>{{p.name}}</label>
```

and in the controller, change the corresponding value of `line.products[p.name]` every time the value of `products[p.name]` is changed.

Comment: If I remove ng-checked, the check boxes do not change in the table

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this problem myself by using "ng-init" and "ng-checked" ---

- ng-checked - 'checked' the checkbox as form was loaded
- ng-init- bound my checkbox html value attribute to the model

There is a comment above stating that its not good to use ng-init in this manner, but not other solution was provided.

Here is an example using ng-select instead of ng-checked:

```
<select ng-model="formData.country"> 
<option value="US" ng-init="formData.country='US'" ng-selected="true">United States</option>
</select>
```

This binds "US" to model formData.country and selects the value on page load.

Comment: It's a bit late but you should be able to add `$scope.formData.country = 'US';` in your controller to perform the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the functionality you are trying to cover the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbTj5/) might help you. Here is the code:

```
<div style="float:left" ng-app ng-init="products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Book',
    line: 'Books',
    selected: true
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Another Book',
    line: 'Books',
    selected: true
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Toy',
    line: 'Toys',
    selected: false
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Another Toy',
    line: 'Toys',
    selected: false
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Phone',
    selected: true
  }];lineProducts = ['Toys', 'Books']" >
<div style="float:left">
    <div ng-repeat="p in products">
        <div style="font-size: smaller">
            <label>
                <input ng-model="p.selected" type="checkbox"/>
                {{p.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="line in lineProducts">
    {{line}}
    <div ng-repeat="p in products | filter:line">
        <div style="font-size: smaller">
            <label>
                <input ng-model="p.selected" type="checkbox"/>                                    
                {{p.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Also why do you have ids in your html? With angular there is no need in ids, and considering that they are inside ng-repeats they will be ambiguous and therefore useless anyway.

I also agree with Nikos about usage of the ng-init. I used it in my jsfiddle because I am lazy, I would not use it in the production code

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-model there that would provide you two way binding. Checking and unchecking the value would update the value of product.selected

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="p.selected"/>
```