# ng-checked and ng-change radio button not work together - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-change, angularjs-ng-checked

http://plnkr.co/edit/RP9SpO1qGjn5Ua6pZJ3D?p=preview

js

```
angular.module("sampleapp", []).controller('samplecontroller', function($scope,$rootScope) {
  $scope.radii = [
    {id:.25, checked:false, name:"1/4 Mile"},
    {id:.5, checked:false, name:"1/2 Mile"},
    {id:1, checked:false, name:"1 Mile"},
    {id:2, checked:true, name:"2 Mile"},
    {id:3, checked:false, name:"3 Mile"},
    {id:4, checked:false, name:"4 Mile"},
    {id:5, checked:false, name:"5 Mile"}
];

$scope.handleRadioClick = function(){
    alert();

};
});
```

and html

```
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radius"

                   ng-change="handleRadioClick()"
                   ng-checked="radius.checked">

              {{radius.name}}

            </label>
          </div>

      </li>
```

Notice "2 Mile" radio input is checked based on the radii scope structure. Why doesn't the ng-change trigger the function?

If I add ng-model, the function triggers but the ng-checked does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because you are not using `ng-model`:

**[FORKED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/jErapTxb1lbsu0sp1ah8?p=preview)**

```
<div class="radio" ng-repeat="radius in radii" id="selectradius-{{radius.id}}">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radius"

         ng-change="handleRadioClick(selectedRadius)"
         ng-model="radius.checked">

    {{radius.name}}

  </label>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm sorry that I didn't notice that you wanted to have a default radio button checked, if that is the case then the approach you're taking is incorrect. You must consider the model as non-individual parts in a group of radio buttons but as a whole, they are supposed to be one value instead. You don't have to use `ng-repeat`'s radio scope variable instead use another `ng-model` as the `selectedRadius` model. Your input radio needs to have a value, and in this case we'll use `ng-value` to determine the current value of the model.

**[UPDATED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/jErapTxb1lbsu0sp1ah8?p=preview)** [**2014 September**]

**JAVASCRIPT**

***Controller***

```
  $scope.radii = [
    {id:.25, name:"1/4 Mile"},
    {id:.5, name:"1/2 Mile"},
    {id:1, name:"1 Mile"},
    {id:2, name:"2 Mile"},
    {id:3, name:"3 Mile"},
    {id:4, name:"4 Mile"},
    {id:5, name:"5 Mile"}
  ];

  // selected value is {id:2, name:"2 Mile"}
  $scope.selectedRadius = $scope.radii[3];
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="radio" ng-repeat="radius in radii" id="selectradius-{{radius.id}}">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radius"

         ng-change="handleRadioClick(radius)"
         ng-model="selectedRadius"
         ng-value="radius">

    {{radius.name}}

  </label>
</div>
```

[**UPDATED PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2rtZAWruXSnOiIS2z93?p=preview) [**2015 January**]

dcz.switcher's problem below suggested that the solution above does not trigger the `ng-change` event handler when a radio button is reselected. The main problem was that the `ng-model` was referring to the `ng-repeat`'s scope and not to the controller's scope from the second change. To solve this problem you can use the `$parent` property. An alternative would be to use `controllerAs` alias and use the alias itself to access your controller's property. To understand more about scopes in AngularJS, I suggest you **[read more about it in here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)**.

*HTML*

```
<div class="radio" ng-repeat="radius in radii" id="selectradius-{{radius.id}}">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radius"

         ng-change="handleRadioClick($parent.selectedRadius)"
         ng-model="$parent.selectedRadius"
         ng-value="radius">

    {{radius.name}}

  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Although, this does call my function, the default radio is not checked anymore. So I'm giving up on this because apparently there is no way to do both things that I want. I just hope everyone here understands my simple request and understands that there is no solution.

Comment: Plus one for using plural radii :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use default values and everything will work like a charm, no need to $watch scope or anything... and **Yes you need ng-model**

- ng-model - *does all work*
- ng-checked - *makes sure you have CHECKED attribute present*
- ng-change - *will trigger your function on-Change*

**HTML example:**

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    ng-model="row.active"
    ng-checked="row.active"
    ng-true-value="1"
    ng-false-value="0"
    ng-change="update(row)"
/>
<!-- test -->
{{ row.active }}
```

**JS optional:**

```
$scope.update = function(row) {
    console.log('row.active');
}
```

Comment: Seems to make logical sense, but in [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) for `ng-checked` it says: "Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior."

Comment: `ngModel` and `ngChecked` are not meant to be used together. See [AngularJS: ng-model not binding to ng-checked for checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51214831/5535245).

Answer (score 2):

This is because ng-change [requires ngModel to be present.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-change` directive requires the `ng-model` directive to be present.

From the Docs:

> ## ngChange
>
> Note, this directive requires `ngModel` to be present.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

---

### The `ng-model` and `ng-checked` directives should not be used together

From the Docs:

> ## ngChecked
>
> Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside `ngChecked` is truthy.
>
> **Note that this directive should not be used together with `ngModel`**, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-checked Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

Instead set the desired initial value from the controller.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `input[radio]` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)