# ng-change is not working after one selection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457243/ng-checked-and-ng-change-dot-not-work-together-angularjs) solution where @ryeballar gives the answer to the problem as that the scope of ng-repeat and controller are clashing so using either `$parent/controller as` syntax will solve the problem. But somehow in my case, the solution doesn't seem to work. The ng-change is not called at all, even after declaring it as a controller As. Also it is giving me weird output as well.
I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HKqgp9HLfIRe4WlMhJaH) for the same.

HTML

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in renew.items">
     <td>{{item.deviceId}}</td>
     <td>{{item.carName}}</td>
     <td>{{item.regNumber}}</td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="{{item.deviceId}}" ng-model="renew.foo" ng-value="Monthly" ng-change="renew.updatePref(item, 'Monthly')">Monthly
     <input type="radio" ng-value="Yearly" ng-model="renew.bar" name="{{item.deviceId}}" ng-change="renew.updatePref(item, 'Yearly')">Yearly
     </td>
     <td>{{item.planStatus}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Here I have two radio buttons namely Monthly and Yearly created with the same `name = item.deviceId` so that only one remains clicked at a time.
Firstly I have tried a lot of things. Setting ng-value to true so that Monthly is checked initially Which works but ng-change stops working and don't get called on a re-click. Can anybody guess why?The exact behaviour that I want is listed in the  comments in Index.html.

Comment: it's hard to sort out what is going wrong with your code, but you seem to have issues in your code with the scope of `this`;  inside these nested function calls, `this` isn't going to point to the properties outside the function calls.

Comment: also mixing up using `$scope` and `this` in the controller beyond just inside the functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change,
initially

```
vm.foo = 'Monthly'

<input type="radio" name="{{item.deviceId}}" ng-model="renew.foo" ng-value="'Monthly'" ng-click="renew.updatePref(item, 'Monthly')">Monthly
<input type="radio"  name="{{item.deviceId}}" ng-model="renew.bar" ng-value="'Yearly'" ng-click="renew.updatePref(item, 'Yearly')">Yearly
```

you have use ng-change, change event never happen as value for these input remains always same.
use,

```
var vm = this;
```

you are also using `ng-value="Monthly"`, Monthly is `variable (undefiend)` for ng-value. either use `value="Monthly" or ng-value="'Monthly'".`

[Working Demo of Your Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/wCg5SUTwEjCS24GuX4Ys?p=preview)

Comment: I solved it. With your help and some of my targeted guessing. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1MeoCTQUUVi00vklyWeP?p=preview) is the solution There is only one issue remaining here. Why is vm working the way it is. We do `var vm =this`.So as to save the initial value of this in a variable, so that if the context changes for this. We will have the initial value stored. Why is it changing here? My best guess. That ng-repeat is causing the value of this to change and updatePref is not in the purview of ng-repeat's scope hence updatePref is never called if we don't use vm. Am I right?

Comment: for this keyword, http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: There is no relation between ng-repeat transclusion scope and this.updatePref  here. Basically value of foo never changes, so ng-change not occurs and so updatePref is never called.

Comment: you can try this instead of vm for updatePref (`this.updatePref`). This will also work as you are using ng-click.

Comment: I think that does it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is assigning things to $scope when you are using controllerAs

When you make the functions as properties of the controller they work fine

```
 app.controller('testCntrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function($scope, $uibModal) {

       var vm = this;// store reference ALWAYS!
```

Then change all references of $scope to `vm`

```
   //$scope.selectedDevices = [];
   vm.selectedDevices = [];
   //$scope.selected = function(device) {
   vm.selected = function(device) {
        if (device.checked) {
            //$scope.selectedDevices.push(device);
            vm.selectedDevices.push(device);
        } 
      //........
```

[Generally working demo (not all scope conversions done)](http://plnkr.co/edit/xB6CTorkOQsJnEzkANnR?p=preview)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work on Radio Buttons which are present inside the modal. The situation still persists. Could you please modify your solution?