# DOM does not show element.input.checked when checkbox checked with ng-checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I use `ng-checked` to check a checkbox by default when a modal loads and meets a certain condition. However, when I do `if ( item.checked)` on that item, it will return false.

I am using a directive like this.

```
app.directive( 'toggleButtons', [ function () {
    return {
        link: function ( scope, element ) {
            var toggleButtons = element.find( '.input-add-checkbox' )

            function checkState() {
                Array.prototype.forEach.call( toggleButtons, function( each ) {
                    if ( each.checked )
                        each.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#00E0AA"
                    else if ( !each.checked )
                        each.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"
                })
            }

            Array.prototype.forEach.call( toggleButtons, function (each) {
                each.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
                    checkState()
                })
            })

            checkState()
        }
    }
}])
```

And my HTML is like this

```
<label for="listen" type="button" class="type-toggle btn btn-green">
    <input type="radio" id="listen" name="type" value="listen" ng-checked="{{ currentState == 'app.listen' }}" ng-model="contentParams.type" class="input-add-checkbox" />
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
</label>
```

---

To clarify, the item is checked properly, but the style in the JS is not applied on loading the template the directive is in. Another cause might be that it's in an AngularUI modal. I have tried button a timeout on it too, but no joy.

Here is how I use the directive in full.

Comment: In directive ng-checked you shouldn't put "{{" "}}"

Comment: Thanks, that did not fix this problem, though.

Comment: Would you provide a JSFiddle? It'll make this easier to debug

Answer (score 2):

Only use `ng-model` and `value` instead:

```
<input type="radio" id="listen" name="type" 
  value="app.init" 
  ng-model="contentParams.type" class="input-add-checkbox" />
```

That way when the `ng-model` matches with your checkbox's **value** will be selected. And instead of `if(each.checked)` you should check against the value  `if(scope.contentParams && each.value === scope.contentParams.type)`

Other way of solve it is to use `ng-attr` instead, but only will work the first time, and in the `checkState` fn you still will have to check against the `value` and the `scope.contentParams.type`

```
 ng-attr-checked="{{contentParams.type ==='app.listen'}}
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hxdf1s?p=preview) is a working example

Comment: using 'ng-model' and 'value' seems to be the way to go, well done!

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Did not know matching model with value would do that. Great! Points well spent.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ng-checked and ng-model together. Use either ng-checked + ng-click, or ng-model + ng-change.

Similar question: [AngularJS: ng-model not binding to ng-checked for checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601018/angularjs-ng-model-not-binding-to-ng-checked-for-checkboxes)

Comment: Thanks. But actually after getting rid of `ng-checked`, the result was the same. The check box is checked properly and has the CSS from my `styles.css` file. But the CSS I'm trying to apply with the directive is not applied.