# Binding checkbox to model and check/unchecking it in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a the following HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="test in lists.Tests">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cbxAcceptTest" ng-checked="{{test.IsAccepted}}"  ng-click="testSelection($event,{{test}})" />
    </label>
</li>
```

and the testSelection method as :

```
$scope.testSelection = function ($event, test) {
    if (test.IsAccepted) {
        alert('accept');
    }
    else {
        alert('reject');
    }

};
```

I am not able to trigger this method on ngClick, It works on ngChecked, but then I have to use ngModel, which Ive read does not go with ngChecked in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601018/angularjs-ng-model-not-binding-to-ng-checked-for-checkboxes).

Comment: ng-click="testSelection()" this will call your method which is in controller

Comment: I need to send parameters to the method as well to update the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I have something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.auto" ng-click="onAutoClick(item)" />
    </label>
</li>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.onAutoClick = function(item) {
  if(item.auto){
     // checked (true condition)
  } else  {
     // unchecked ( false condition)
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the curly braces around test when you pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tIiMDWeyVfaofABHnQ0w?p=preview).

In HTML you need remove your curly braces

```
  <li ng-repeat="test in lists.Tests">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cbxAcceptTest" ng-checked="{{test.IsAccepted}}"  ng-click="testSelection(test)" />
    </label>
```