# AngularJS: ngChecked not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-checked

I have the following radio button:

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="option.text" ng-model="selected.value" name="option" ng-checked="poll_post.poll_option_id == option.id">
```

I have double checked `poll_post.poll_option_id` and `option.id` are equal. So the expression inside ng-checked is evaluated to true. But in the view, the option is not checked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please add a plunker or something so we can see the whole

Comment: I'll add that, but any chance I am doing something wrong that is obvious?

Comment: i think your expression is not right.... code plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't use ngModel and ngChecked together.
ngChecked is a one-way binding, that is it will only check the value of the expression and set the input accordingly but if you change the value of the input it won't pass the value to the variable it's bound to.
On the other hand, ngModel will both check the value of the variable it's bound to and will set the value of the variable should the input change.
The advantage of ngChecked over ngModel is that you can use an expression instead of a variable.

Still, if both are present ngModel "wins" over ngChecked (ngChecked has priority 100 while ngModel has priority 1, search "priority" here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile ) and the change of the ngChecked expression won't get passed to the variable ngModel is bound to

You can see in this Plunker that even though `Val1` has `checked="true"` the variable `$scope.selected` is set to `Val2` so ng-model wins over ng-checked http://plnkr.co/edit/nae3b46KNzFKVTqEQPG3?p=preview

If you want to programmatically change the status of the checkbox You should edit the variable you have bound your ng-model to, or remove ng-model and leave just ng-checked (that depends on what you are doing).

For more info:
[AngularJS: ng-model not binding to ng-checked for checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601018/angularjs-ng-model-not-binding-to-ng-checked-for-checkboxes)
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked