# Angularjs ng-show not working with checkbox with default value true in jsp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

```
             <tr> 
             <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="<%=cat4%>" ng-checked="true"> </td>
            <td>
            <%=cat2%>
             </td>
             <td><input type="text" class="txt" ng-show="<%=cat4%>" placeholder="Enter Price per <%=cat2%>" value="<%=temps[i]%>"></td>    
            </tr>
```

I want to display the text box when checkbox is checked. The checkbox is by default checked. When the check box is unchecked then the text box should be hidden. Using the above code the checkbox is checked but the textbox is not displayed (when the form loads). When I uncheck and again check the checkbox then only the text box is displayed. What changes are needed in the code?

Comment: this may help you http://jsfiddle.net/ucmL2/

Comment: putting ng-checked="true" and running the code,  the checkbox is checked but text box is not displayed in above link.

Comment: `ngModel and ngChecked are not meant to be used together` try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601018/angularjs-ng-model-not-binding-to-ng-checked-for-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

unchecking it doesn't make it false

use `ng-change` to turn it for false to true and vice versa