# not getting selected checkbox id along with ng-checked condition in checkboxes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I Have a html table which is binding using AngularJs.

```
 <tr class="gradeX" ng-repeat="itm in usersList">
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="itm.checkstatus == 1" ng-model="itm.selected" value="{{itm.ID}}" /></td>
                                <td> {{itm.FirstName}}</td>

                                <td>{{itm.Email}}</td>

                            </tr>
```

During ng-repeat i already add a condition that if itm.chekstatus=1 then checkbox will check otherwise not.But now i want to get all selected checkbox id  when a button is clicked.
here is my code for getting the selected checkboxid.

```
$scope.AddEvent = function (Data) {

            debugger
            $scope.UserNameArray = [];


            angular.forEach($scope.usersList, function (itm) {
                if (itm.selected) $scope.UserNameArray.push(itm.ID);
            })
            var obj = {
                idList: $scope.UserNameArray
            }
            if ($scope.UserNameArray.length > 0) {

                    $http({
                        url: "EventRoute/getAllSelectedUserID",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: obj,
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        }
                    }).success(function (response) {


                        }

                    })
                    .error(function (error) {
                        alert(error);
                    });
                }



        }
```

my problem is that when i add a condition ng-checked="itm.checkstatus == 1" along with ng-model="itm.selected" value="{{itm.ID}}" then 
i am not getting the selected checkboxid.But when i remove the condition ng-checked="itm.checkstatus == 1" then i am getting the selected checkbox id.
How to do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ngModel and ngChecked are not meant to be used together.
>
> ngChecked is expecting an expression, so by saying ng-checked="true",
>   you're basically saying that the checkbox will always be checked by
>   default. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601018/angularjs-ng-model-not-binding-to-ng-checked-for-checkboxes)

Actually ng-model selected is doing a action ng checked for you. Instead of adding the directive **ng-checked** add 
**ng-init** `(ng-init="itm.selected=itm.checkstatus==1;")`

```
<tr class="gradeX" ng-repeat="itm in usersList" ng-init="itm.selected=itm.checkstatus==1;">
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="itm.selected" value="{{itm.ID}}" /></td>
                                <td> {{itm.FirstName}}</td>

                                <td>{{itm.Email}}</td>

                            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

With ng-model you don't have to use ng-checked directive. 
To get the values of all the selected checkboxes

```
    angular.forEach($scope.usersList, function (itm) {
       if (itm.selected) $scope.UserNameArray.push(itm.ID);
    })
```

This code that you wrote yourself should get all the ids of the checked checkboxes.

Comment: i have already written this code.my problem is that it is working when i remove the ng-checked conditon.without ng-cheked it is working but when i add ng-checked condition it is not working

Comment: Jeevanandan J pointed out the same mistake that I did that ng-model and ng-checked don't have to be used together because ng-model is doing what ng-checked should do already behind the scene. Hope that clarifies your concept