# Pre-checked inputbox are not being serialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-checked

I have a simple code that list many colors and check if some has been chosen previamente by user(this is setted on code but in really its come from the database).
When i submit the form, the pre-checked inputs don't are listed in array and if i uncheck some, this wont be removed from array.

```js
const SampleApp = angular.module('SampleApp', [])

SampleApp.controller('sampleAppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'yellow', 'pink', 'white']
    $scope.preChecked = ['green', 'pink']
    $scope.user = { colors: [] }
    $scope.colorArr = []

    $scope.isUserColor = color => {
         return $scope.preChecked.some(uColor => color === uColor)
    }

    $scope.handleSubmit = () => {
        const filteredColors = $scope.colors.filter((color, index) => {
            return $scope.user.colors.some((uColor, uIndex) => {
                 return index === uIndex
            })
        })
        $scope.colorArr = filteredColors
    }    
})
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="SampleApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div ng-controller="sampleAppController">
        <form ng-submit="handleSubmit()">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="color in colors">
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="{{color}}"
                        id="{{color}}"
                        ng-checked="isUserColor(color)"
                        ng-model="user.colors[$index]"
                        value="{{color}}"
                    >
                    <label for="{{color}}">{{color}}</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div>{{colorArr}}</div>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `ng-model` and `ng-checked` together. Use `ng-model` for two-way binding, `ng-checked` for one-way binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `ng-model` and `ng-checked` directives should not be used together<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51214831/5535245)</sup>

From the Docs:

> ## ngChecked
>
> Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside `ngChecked` is truthy.
>
> **Note that this directive should not be used together with `ngModel`**, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.
>
> — [AngularJS ng-checked Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

---

Don't use `ng-model` and `ng-checked` together. Use `ng-model` for two-way binding, `ng-checked` for one-way binding.

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="color in colors">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="{{color}}"
            id="{{color}}"
            ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶e̶d̶=̶"̶i̶s̶U̶s̶e̶r̶C̶o̶l̶o̶r̶(̶c̶o̶l̶o̶r̶)̶"̶
            ng-model="user.colors[$index]"
            ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶c̶o̶l̶o̶r̶}̶}̶"̶
        >
        <label for="{{color}}">{{color}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Instead initialize the models from the controller:

```
$scope.user = { colors: [] };
$scope.user.colors = $scope.colors.map(c => $scope.preChecked.some(_ => _ == c));
```

Comment: this solved my problem, thank you!