# ng-checked is true but not enabled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My data looks like, where each entry is `log`, coming from `SupportService`

```
var getDummyLogsForNow = function () {
    return [
        {
            "fileName": "file A",
            "location": "logs/fileA",
            "size": "20000",
            "lastUpdated": "May 04, 2015 09:21PM"
        },
        {
            "fileName": "file B",
            "location": "logs/fileB",
            "size": "4034300",
            "lastUpdated": "May 01, 2015 01:21PM"
        },
        {
            "fileName": "file C",
            "location": "logs/fileC",
            "size": "53437000",
            "lastUpdated": "May 02, 2015 03:11PM"
        }
    ]
};

return {
    logs: getDummyLogsForNow()
};
```

In my controller, I use it as

```
$scope.logs = SupportService.logs;
$scope.selectedLogs = ["file C"];
```

and this is how I print them up on HTML table

```
    <table class="logsTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>Last Updated</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="log in logs">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox"
                       ng-checked="selectedLogs.indexOf(log.fileName) != -1"
                       ng-click="toggleSelect(log)">
            </td>
            <td>{{log.fileName}}</td>
            <td>{{log.lastUpdated}}</td>
            <td>{{log.size}}</td>
            <!--<td>{{log.location}}</td>-->
            <td>{{selectedLogs.indexOf(log.fileName) != -1}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Even though one of the entries if `true`, the `checkbox` is not checked. All I see is

[image]

What's the issue here?

Comment: not really, I am not using `ngModel` here

Comment: Each repeated element gets it's own scope so try `$parent.$parent.selectedLogs.indexOf(log.fileName) != -1`.

Comment: That did not help either @R3tep. The weird thing is that when I refresh page, I see all of them enabled and suddenly disappear

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226439/angularjs-doesnt-bind-ng-checked-with-ng-model)  (They use ng-repeat like you)

Comment: I put your example in a plunker as-is - it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/yKpq8QwPc6ngVxAcUxAB?p=preview

Comment: Very interesting, I am not sure what is screwed up in my page then `:(`

Comment: Opened this plunker and it's not working

Comment: Browser Issue! Chrome acting weird (good in InCognito Mode), works well on Safari

Comment: I am using Firefox and the same issue. Private browsing didnt help here :/
What did help is to move the ng-app and ng-controller directives to body and div container elements as in: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZEn55txecJRwhMQGdR4Y?p=preview
Maybe that's the same case in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have something wrong with referencing your model. I've simplified your example (dropped the service) and have a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/fpnte4td/6/

So probably there must be something in the controller or service... Can you try defining the sample data directly in the controller, like below?

```
$scope.logs = [{
        "fileName": "file A",
        "location": "logs/fileA",
        "size": "20000",
        "lastUpdated": "May 04, 2015 09:21PM"
    },{
        "fileName": "file B",
        "location": "logs/fileB",
        "size": "4034300",
        "lastUpdated": "May 01, 2015 01:21PM"
    },{
        "fileName": "file C",
        "location": "logs/fileC",
        "size": "53437000",
        "lastUpdated": "May 02, 2015 03:11PM"
    }
];
```

If this doesn't help, please post full body of the service and controller (skip irrelevant parts)

Comment: This should be a comment - not an answer - since it doesn't actually answer the question